# Lego Set ID with lime green and grey pieces?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I need your help to identify this set.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are parts from

[8192-1: Lime Racer](https://brickset.com/sets/8192-1/Lime-Racer)
[image]
besed on the [Slope, Curved 2 x 2 Lip, No Studs with 'RUN' and 'V8' Pattern Model Left (Sticker) - Set 8192](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30602pb037L#T=C&C=85)

and parts from

[7052-1: UFO Abduction](https://brickset.com/sets/7052-1/UFO-Abduction)
[image]
based on the [Slope 33 3 x 2 with Alien Insignia Pattern (Sticker) - Set 7052](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3298pb048&idColor=86#T=C&C=86)